# Magento 2: Run commands in Docker

Tags: magento2, cli, docker

I am new to docker and devbox. I have setup DevBox Successfully and its working fine in a local system. I need information how to

- run CLI ie. php bin/magento cache:flush
- access phpmyadmin

My local setup details:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Magento Root files: D:\devbox\shared\webroot. I had created devbox in D drive.
- Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22
- local magento working at : http://127.0.0.1:32770/
  and admin at: http://127.0.0.1:32770/admin/

Please comment if more information required.

**Update:**  Command "docker ps -a" displayed container then I executed the clean command but it's not working. Please suggest what path I am missing here:

[image]

Comment: Not sure about devbox, but in docker you will need enter php container and run php/magento from there. Something like 'docker exec -t -i  containername /bin/bash'

Comment: I need something like this. How to get correct container name here?

Comment: 'docker ps -a' shows all containers with details

Comment: Thanks and Please check updated p
ost with command screen shot.

Comment: There is no d: folder in your docker container, check where are you first after entering container. `docker exec -t -i containername /bin/bash` then `ls -la`.
Your magento files probably based somewhere like `/var/www/`
`docker exec -ti magento2devbox_web_302cced7f3c022680a96a06b1fe1bdbe php /var/www/webroot/bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: pls check here - http://prntscr.com/em6ji3 and what next? Thank you very much and its seems I am near to it.

Comment: 1. `cd magento2`
2. `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55678/discussion-between-jai-and-jev-mokrousov).

Answer (score 6):

The better way is to open your container, you can use the command:

```
docker exec -ti CONTAINER_NAME bash
```

so you will enter into docker container and use all commands that you want execute normally.

> Remember to access the **web** container and not the **db**

To exit you can use the command `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

you can run this commands in this way -

`docker exec -ti CONTAINTER_NAME php /absolute/path/to/magento_file cache:clean`

or if you don't want to run this as root

`docker exec -ti CONTAINTER_NAME sudo -g GROUP_NAME  php /absolute/path/to/magento_file cache:clean`

Comment: docker exec -ti magento2devbox_web_302cced7f3c022680a96a06b1fe1bdbe php d:/devbox/shared/webroot/bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: I ran above command but its displaying message: Could not open input file: d:/devbox/shared/webroot/bin/magento. I try by modifying in all ways but its not working.

Comment: Please check updated post with command screen shot.

Comment: d:/path
this is your local mashine path
you should use absolute path in container 
like /var/www/... 
go inside container, find bin/magento file and copy its absolute path

Comment: Where i can find container name?